# How to build SQL to capture most unique value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a query results with SQL.  Here is my table:

```
CUST_ID    ORDER_ID    STORE_FREQUENCY   
---------- ----------- ---------------
100         20122        500            
100         20100        500        
100         20100        737            
200         20119        287            
300         20130        434            
300         20150        434            
300         20130        434            
300         20120        120
```

The expected output is:

```
CUST_ID   UNIQUE_ORDERS     TOP_STORE   
--------- ----------------- ---------
  100        2               737        
  200        1               287        
  300        3               434
```

The requirement for the output is:

- TOP_STORE = Per CUST_ID, sort the STORE_FREQUENCY column by DESC and get the greatest store frequency
- UNIQUE_ORDERS = Per CUST_ID, the number of unique ORDER_IDs in the column

I have started this SELECT statement, but having difficulties completing it to include the 2 columns correctly:

```
Select cust_id, Count(order_id) as unique_orders
From ORDERS_TABLE
Group By Order_ID
```

Can you help me complete the 2 columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use aggregate functions such as `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT  CUST_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID), MAX(STORE_FREQUENCY )
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY CUST_ID
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3807b/2).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the top store should be the store with the greatest number of orders.  If so, then `CUST_ID` 100 should have store `500` as the top store, not `737`.  In other words, I would expect the following output:

[image]

This requirement changes the query strategy, because we no longer can just do a single simple aggregation over the entire table.  One approach is to do a separate calculation to find the top store for each customer, then join that result to a query similar to the other answers.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CUST_ID, STORE_FREQUENCY, cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CUST_ID, STORE_FREQUENCY,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID, STORE_FREQUENCY) cnt
        FROM yourTable
    ) t
)

SELECT
    t1.CUST_ID,
    t1.UNIQUE_ORDERS,
    t2.TOP_STORE
FROM
(
    SELECT CUST_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID) AS UNIQUE_ORDERS
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CUST_ID
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CUST_ID, STORE_FREQUENCY AS TOP_STORE
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
) t2
    ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID;
```

### Demo